# jQuery css is not working for mobile

Tags: jquery, css, magento, mobile

Referring to my question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190993/magento-2-add-custom-tab-to-product-details-page-conditionally/190996#190996

As suggested in the answer, I am trying to hide the custom tab if response is "No Data to display!".

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
                        var me = $(this);
                        if ( me.data('requestRunning') ) {
                            return;
                        }
                        me.data('requestRunning', true);
                        //$(document).on('click', '#tab-label-nutrition', function() {
                                    var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('nutrition/nutrition/index') ?>";
                                    var currentSku1 = '<?php echo $currentSku; ?>';
                                    if(currentSku1 && $(".nutritionFactsContent").children().length == 0){
                                            $.ajax({
                                                    url: customurl,
                                                    type: 'POST',                       
                                                    dataType: 'html',
                                                    showLoader: true,
                                                    data: {
                                                            sku: currentSku1,                    
                                                    },
                                                    complete: function(responseData) {
                            if (responseData.responseText == 'No Data to display!') {
                                jQuery('#tab-label-nutrition').hide();
                            } else {
                                alert('hi');
                                jQuery('#tab-label-nutrition').css('display', 'inline-block');
                            }
                            $('.nutritionFactsContent').append(responseData.responseText);
                            console.log('ajax completed');
                            me.data('requestRunning', false);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                        }
                    });
                }
                //});//click event
            });
```

This works well on desktop. However does not work on mobile devices. The alert in the else part is executed though just the css is not applied.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Add this after your `css()` line and look in the console. What is the output? `console.log(jQuery('#tab-label-nutrition').css('display'));`

Comment: added this 'alert(jQuery('#tab-label-nutrition').css('display'));'. Sometimes it displays none and sometimes inline-block

Comment: But that would be correct. Those are your two options. `hide()` sets `display` to `none` and in `else` you set it to `inline-block` (you could use `show()` here btw.). That means that when `display` is `none` your response is "No Data to display!". Log it in the console and have a look ...

Comment: tried with show() as well.

Comment: Yes, but have you looked at the exact output of your ajax? Maybe the result is "No Data to display!" when display isn't `inline-block`?

Comment: This did the trick. Added jQuery('.mobile-detail #tab-label-nutrition').css('display', 'inline-block'); However I don't understand why did I have to write the hierarchy.

Comment: The same for me. I tried the hierarchy trick. Didn’t work out for me. I ended up defining classes instead of styling the element directly. Weird (mobile) bug in my eyes.

Comment: It wasn't the bug in my case. I realized it later that I had two separate divs. One for mobile and one for desktop. It should work in any case though as the class is same.